# How to join to tables with certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:  accounts and authorizations.

Accounts Table has the full name and id of both customers and agents.  The authorizations table has the id of the customer and agent who is under that customer. The accounts table has the Full Name, and id of both the agent and the customer.

I keep getting the agent name instead of the customer name.  not sure how to fix this!

Update:  I was able to get the right id but still the name of the customer doesn't show up.
Code:

```
//Query
$sql = "SELECT authorizations.customer_id, accounts.fullname
        FROM authorizations
        INNER JOIN accounts ON
        authorizations.system_id = accounts.authorizating_customer
        WHERE authorizations.agent_id = '$did'";

$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();
echo "";
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
    $name = mysql_result($result, $i, "fullname");
    echo "";
    echo "";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: You're joining the table with itself, instead of joining accounts `FROM authorizations LEFT JOIN authorizations`

Comment: Just for the record: echo ""; is as useful as trying to display nothing. Worse yet; you are. It's clutter. You can remove it, as it doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            authorizations.customer_id, 
            accounts.fullname 
        FROM 
            authorizations 
                LEFT JOIN 
                    accounts 
                ON 
                    accounts.authorizing_person = authorizations.customer_id 
        WHERE 
            authorizations.agent_id = '$agentid' 
        ORDER BY 
            accounts.id DESC";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

echo "";

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

    $name = mysql_result($result,$i,"fullname");
    echo "";
    echo "";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Hi i tried that.  But it gives me the agents name not the customers name.

Comment: Well, then try changing the `accounts.fullname` to the column name of the customer name.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the structure of your tables, but you can follow this pseudo code

```
SELECT name_of_person FROM accounts WHERE authorizing_person = (SELECT authorizing_person FROM authorization WHERE agent_id = '$agentid'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  Just had to use the customer_id instead of authorizing_customer.